# xcode IBOutlet won't connect to codes

Tags: ios

I am using xcode 4.3

I have a huge problem:

I started creating an application using storyboard for the ipad. At first i added my objects in interface builder, and then I dragged the blue line to the .h file and xcode made the connection and created a:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
```

with the filled up circle.

But after a few days, I tried to add a UIScrollView. I added the object to the storyboard, and dragged the line, but it would not connect and create a property. So I made first the codes,and tried to link, but same problem. So I deleated the scroll view and inserted again a button and lable. BUT NOW ANY OBJECT WON'T LINK TO THE CODES IN ANY WAY!!! WHY? To solve the problem I have to start again from the biginning!!

I create:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button2;
```

drag the line: NO
drag to view controller: NO
did the opposite: NO

WHY???

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the scene an instance of class ViewController instead of UIViewController, which is the default. You can change this in the identity inspector (third tab in the utilities)

Comment: Cant believe I missed it, Thanks a bunch. @Sam

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to drag the line to anything other than a button you're not going to have any success.

If you want to drag the line to a scrollview, you need to change the declaration to

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollview *scrollView;
                                     //^^^^^^^^^^^^ this type determines what it links to in interface-builder
```

Comment: yea, I did that, i forgot to write it:+

Comment: I'm not sure then, you'll have to provide some better details as to whats going wrong, I don't know if I fully understand what the case is other than "it doesn't work"